# Display selected categories at top of publish category tab

Tags: categories

We have over 1000 categories visible on the Publish Form (inherited!). I want to be able to show the moderators the selected categories at a glance instead of them having to scroll through all 1000. Is there an extension out there that does this, or will I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortuantely I don't know of any addons that will do this, however using the instructions field you could inject some javascript into the publish page. Something [like this](http://charlie.griefer.com/blog/2009/08/14/jquery-accessing-checked-checkboxes/) would probably get you a good chunk of the way there.